# How can I make a newline in an Openoffice.org Calc formula?

Tags: openoffice, openoffice-calc, newlines

I have a text cell I2 and a text cell J2. I want cell K2 to be the contents of I2 concatenated with a newline and the contents of J2. How can I do this?

```
I2    J2    K2
big   dog   big
            dog
```

I've tried using Ctrl-Enter in various places and char(10) and char(13) to no avail. The newline always disappears.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like `char(10)` actually did the trick, but it's just not visible in the sheet. When the data from the spreadsheet is used in a mail merge later (for address labels), the newline is there!

Comment: The behavior in general is fixed in OpenOffice 3.2:

http://www.openoffice.org/dev_docs/features/3.2/#calc_newlines

Answer (score 4):

On Linux you can use:

```
=CONCATENATE("line 1";char(10);"line2")
```

Comment: As Jim said below, you can do this in OpenOffice 3.2+ now.  Worked for me on Windows OO 3.3.

Answer (score 1):

Type <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> in an unused cell, then in the formula for `K2` use `I2&(address of the cell with the CTRL+Enter)&J2`

I stumbled upon it by accident (playing a hunch) and it displays correctly and prints correctly...